# Multiple NSPopover ecrasing each other

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to put two NSPopover on two Help Buttons on a .xib file.

To do so, I declared in my .h

```
@interface ExportPreferences : NSPreferencePane <NSPopoverDelegate>
{
    NSWindow *window;
    NSPopover *popover;
    NSUserDefaults *prefs;
    NSMutableArray *myArran;
    IBOutlet NSButton *images;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *modalities;
    IBOutlet NSPathControl *path;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *tree;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *extension;
}
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopover *popover;

@end
```

And two different methods in my .m :

```
- (IBAction) showInfoTreePopover {
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
}
- (IBAction) showInfoTypePopover {
    [[self popover] showRelativeToRect:[sender bounds] ofView:sender preferredEdge:NSMaxXEdge];
}
```

Then, in my .xib I declared

- A Popover with its Popover View Controller
- A Custom View
- A Label (on the CV)

And I linked :

- The Help Button to its corresponding method (one for the Tree, one for the Type)
- The File's Owner to the Popover
- The Popover View Controller to the Custom View

Since I do have two NSPopover to implement, I did all of this twice, two Popover, two Popover View Controller, two Custom View, two labels.

When I compile, everything goes right, but when I test it, it appears that only my second Popover shows up on the two buttons. It seems that implementing the second Popover, erased the first one.

how may I patch that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I answered my own question but I think I might give the answer if anyone faces the same problem.

When using two NSPopovers, I had to declare two different Outlets,

```
NSPopover *treePopover;
NSPopover *typePopover;
```

Also, two properties

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopover *treePopover;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPopover *typePopover;
```

And now, the linking works perfectly.